# Functions fopen/calloc/malloc and and ways of their replacement

Tags: c

I want to make a simple program (but difficult for me), which will find contacts by letters (parts of the name are entered using numbers) and by numbers (parts of the number). Input - numbers, from the standard input (txt file), output - contacts that contain these numbers (letters). The contact file looks like

(name)
(number)
(name)
(…)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME (128)
#define MAX_NUM (32)
/*
IN :
contacts.txt :
    Sad Mirrow
    38074025
    Deniel Kovalski
    78032596
    Miky Trance
    88055535
    Martin Worried
    77432651

    96 [key number from standard entry]

OUT:

    Deniel Kovalski 
    [because 96 matches in his number]
    Martin Worried
    [96 matches in his name Wo]
*/


typedef struct Contact {
    char* name;
    char* number;
} Contact;

char matchTable[10][9] = {
    "0+", "1", "2abcABC", "3defDEF", "4ghiGHI",
    "5jklJKL", "6mnoMNO", "7pqrsPQRS", "8tuvTUV", "9wxyWXY"
};


bool find(char c, char key){

    int j = key - '0';
    for (int i = 0; matchTable[j][i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (c == matchTable[j][i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;

}

bool matches(char* src, char* key){

    unsigned int i,j;

    for (i = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++){
        int tmp = i;
        for (j = 0; key[j] != '\0'; j++){
            if (find(src[tmp], key[j]))
                tmp++;
            else
                break;
        }
        if (j == strlen(key))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){

    char key[MAX_NUM];
    scanf("%s", key);
    size_t arrSize = 32;

    Contact* contacts = malloc(arrSize * sizeof(Contact));

    int k = 0;
    size_t nameSize = MAX_NAME;
    size_t numSize = MAX_NUM;
    char *nameBuf = malloc(MAX_NAME);
    char *numBuf = malloc(MAX_NUM);

    FILE* f = fopen("contacts.txt", "r");


    while (fgets(nameBuf, nameSize, f)
            && fgets(numBuf, numSize, f)){
        contacts[k].name = malloc(MAX_NAME);
        contacts[k].number = malloc(MAX_NUM);
        strcpy(contacts[k].name, nameBuf);
        strcpy(contacts[k].number, numBuf);

        k++;
        if (k == arrSize);
            arrSize <<= 1;
        contacts = realloc(contacts, arrSize * sizeof(Contact));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        bool matchesName = matches(contacts[i].name, key);
        bool matchesNumber = matches(contacts[i].number, key);

        if (matchesName || matchesNumber)
            printf("%s\n", contacts[i].name);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        free(contacts[i].name);
        free(contacts[i].number);
    }
    free(contacts);
    free(nameBuf);
    free(numBuf);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

At first we did as we could. Then was a time to fulfill the conditions of the task and the problem came. It needs to be done without malloc/calloc/fopen. I tried to fix everything, but I ran into a problem that the program does not work and it seems to me that I'm confused.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_NAME (128)
#define MAX_NUM (64)

struct Folio
{
    char name[1000];
    char num[1000];
};

static char matchTable[10][9] = {
    "0+", "1", "2abcABC", "3defDEF", "4ghiGHI",
    "5jklJKL", "6mnoMNO", "7pqrsPQRS", "8tuvTUV", "9wxyWXY"
};


int find(char c, char key){

    int j = key - '0';
    for (int i = 0; matchTable[j][i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (c == matchTable[j][i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}

int matches(char* src, char* key){

   unsigned int i,j;

    for (i = 0; src[i] != '\0'; i++){
        unsigned int tmp = i;
        for (j = 0; key[j] != '\0'; j++){
            if (find(src[tmp], key[j]))
                tmp++;
            else
                break;
        }
        if (j == strlen(key))
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(){

    char key[MAX_NUM];
    scanf("%s", key);

    struct Folio contacts[42]; //Entry entries[42]

    int contacts_count = 0; //entries_count = 0;


    //FILE* f = fopen("seznam.txt", "r");
    char name[1000];
    char num[1000]; //number[1000]



    while (fgets(name, MAX_NAME, stdin) != NULL && fgets(num, MAX_NUM, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        // copy to struct
        strcpy(contacts[contacts_count].name, name);
        strcpy(contacts[contacts_count].num, num);

        contacts_count++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < contacts_count; i++){
        int matchesName = matches(contacts[contacts_count].name, key);
        int matchesNumber = matches(contacts[contacts_count].num, key);

        if (matchesName || matchesNumber)
            printf("%s%s\n", contacts[contacts_count].name, contacts[contacts_count].num);
    }

    //fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to ask the help of experienced programmers.

Comment: You can't use files without opening it.

Answer (score 0):

`matchTable[10][9]` is too small to save `"7pqrsPQRS"` as a *string* as needed in `matchTable[j][i] != '\0';`.  Needs 10.

Suggest

```
//static char matchTable[10][9] = {
//    "0+", "1", "2abcABC", "3defDEF", "4ghiGHI",
//    "5jklJKL", "6mnoMNO", "7pqrsPQRS", "8tuvTUV", "9wxyWXY"
//};

static char *matchTable[10] = {
    "0+", "1", "2abcABC", "3defDEF", "4ghiGHI",
    "5jklJKL", "6mnoMNO", "7pqrsPQRS", "8tuvTUV", "9wxyWXY"
};
```

---

Perhaps other issues too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main issue is the the search logic. Code loops over all contacts, but will attempt a match against the a non-existing contacts entry.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < contacts_count; i++){
        int matchesName = matches(contacts[contacts_count].name, key);
        int matchesNumber = matches(contacts[contacts_count].num, key);
        ...
```

Should this use the i-th contacts ?

```
   for (int i = 0; i < contacts_count; i++){
        int matchesName = matches(contacts[i].name, key);
        int matchesNumber = matches(contacts[i].num, key);
        if (matchesName || matchesNumber)
            printf("%s%s\n", contacts[i].name, contacts[contacts_count].num);
    }
```

Or even

```
   for (int i = 0; i < contacts_count; i++){
        struct Folio con_p = &contacts[i] ;
        int matchesName = matches(con_p->name, key);
        int matchesNumber = matches(con_p->num, key);
        if (matchesName || matchesNumber)
            printf("%s%s\n", con_p->name, con_p->num);
    }
```

Also take a look at answer from `chux - Reinstate Monica`